# Regex to validate password

Tags: regex, passwords

I've looked on here for some ideas but I still seem to be struggling with coming up with a regular expression to meet my requirements.

I need a regular expression to check a password format, the criteria are:

- At least 1 uppercase letter
- At least 1 number
- Only alphanumeric characters (no special characters)
- At least 8 characters long

The regular expression I'm using is:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$
```

However this is also allowing characters like `!$&`.

Is there a modification I need to make to this to get it to stop these special characters being accepted?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the last part `.{8,}` to `[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}`

```
 ^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$
```

Comment: @M42 Why doesn't this: `^(?=.*[\!\#\@\$\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\*\-\+\-\_\.\:\;\,\]\[\{\}])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}$` work if i wanted to allow special chars as well?

Comment: @tastro: you have to replace the last `[a-zA-Z\d]{8,}` by `.{8,}`.

Comment: @M42 thank, but it still doesn't work. Could you please explain what ?=.* does? I know that `a?` allows an `a` or no `a` at all. Just don't know what the question mark (?) does when you put an equals (=) behind it.

Comment: @tastro: The notation `(?=.....)` is a positive look ahead. Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html but this doesn't work in some regex flavour. If you have more questions, it'll be better to ask another question than have a discution in the comment part :-)

Comment: @M42 done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25411819/regex-regular-expression-for-password-validation Thanks again!