# secured regular expression that restrict specific special characters

Tags: php, regex

I tried to create regular expression with specification below

- any alphabetic character (at least one)
- any numeric character (at least one)
- no spaces
- accept all special characters (except `",;&|'`)

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*\s)((?!.*[",;&|'])|(?=(.*\W){1,}))(?!.*[",;&|'])$
```

This is the one I tried.
What I can do with this?

Comment: Please show the expression you tried, and what it should match, and what it shouldn't match.

Comment: try including only what you need instead of trying to exclude all not needed. What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to validate password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698816/regex-to-validate-password)

Answer (score 2):

Question is still vague in nature, please provide some examples of accepted strings.

Just to get you started you can use:

- character class in a negative lookahead
- Don't forget start & end anchors:

Regex:

```
/^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?!.*?[ ",;&|']).+$/i
```

This regex will match 1 or more characters that are not one of  `",;&|'` and atleast one digit and `a-z` alpgabet is required.

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/nxdi79ZcRx

In PHP use it like this:

```
'/^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[a-z])(?!.*?[ ",;&|\']).+$/i'
```

Comment: But this will match just for instance the letters 'ab' i believe the minimum wanted is 1 letter and 1 number e.g. 'a1', but i may be wrong

Comment: I think he wants any string that matches at least one character AND at least one numeric character AND no specials EXCEPT for `",;&|'`

Comment: @Srb1313711: By no means this is my final answer since question is still pretty vague as `any alphabetic character (at least one) any numeric character (at least one) no spaces special characters` can mean anything.

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for ur response. The regex should not accept ", ; & | ' special characters. But the regex which you provided accepts those special character. I tried with the link only.

Comment: Works like a charm in the tester i use:-)

Comment: Its works now.. Thanks. Is // is the escape sequence that should be used for " and  ' since I ll quote this regex with single quotes.

Comment: I would have used `\s` instead of a literal space character.  I think it's safe to assume all whitespace characters are verboten.